# Output remains constant which actually should keep changing

Tags: c++

I am working on developing an epidemic model called SIR model in which t represents time when executed should should keep changing time from 0 to 10 but my output remains constant at 10. what am i doing wrong in the following code?

```
#include<iostream>
 #include<cmath>
 using namespace std;
 class SIR
 {

  private:

       double t,susceptible,infected,recover,states[3];
       double diffstate[3],dt;
       double b,k;
       double time;

  public:

       SIR();
       SIR(double bCurr, double kCurr, double deltat, double sCurr, double iCurr, double maxtime);
       ~SIR();

        void stepStates(double states[3]);
        void Runge_Kutta();
        void printResult();
};

    SIR::SIR(double bCurr, double kCurr, double deltat, double sCurr,double iCurr, double maxtime)
{
      b = bCurr;
      k =kCurr;
      dt = deltat;
      susceptible=sCurr;
      infected = iCurr;
      recover = 1 - susceptible - infected;
      time = maxtime;
  }

    SIR::~SIR(){}

    void SIR::stepStates(double states[3])
    {
      diffstate[0] = - b*states[0]*states[1];
      diffstate[1] = b*states[0]*states[1] - k*states[1];
      diffstate[2] = k*states[1];

    }

    void SIR::Runge_Kutta()
    {
       int i= 0;
       double y1[3], y2[3], y3[3], y4[3];
       double x[3], initialStates[3];

       initialStates[0]=susceptible; initialStates[1]=infected; initialStates[2]=recover;
       stepStates(initialStates);

         for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              y1[i]=diffstate[i];
              x[i]=initialStates[i]+dt*y1[i]/2;
         }


          stepStates(x);
          for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              y2[i]=diffstate[i];
              x[i]=initialStates[i]+dt*y2[i]/2;
       }

          stepStates(x);
          for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
               y3[i]=diffstate[i];
               x[i]=initialStates[i]+dt*y3[i];
      }

           stepStates(x);
           for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
               y4[i]=diffstate[i];
               x[i]=initialStates[i]+(y1[i]/6 + y2[i]/3 + y3[i]/3 + y4[i]/6)* dt;
      }

    susceptible = x[0];
    infected = x[1];
    recover = x[2];
}

    void SIR::printResult()
    {
        t=0;
        cout <<"t    S    I       R \n"<<endl;
    do
    {
        Runge_Kutta();
        t+=dt;
        cout<<time<<"   "<<susceptible<<"   "<<infected<<"   "<<recover<<"   "<<endl;
    }while(t<time);

}
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        double bCurr = 1.0/2.0;
        double sCurr = 9999999.0/10000000.0;
        double iCurr = 1.0/10000000.0;
        double rCurr = 0.0;
        double kCurr = 1.0/3.0;
        double deltat = 0.01/((bCurr*kCurr)*sCurr);// small step size in time
        std::cout << "time  S    I    R \n" << std::endl;
        double maxtime = 10;

        SIR mySIR(bCurr, kCurr, deltat ,sCurr, iCurr ,  maxtime);
        mySIR.printResult();

    return(0);

    }
```

Comment: Take a closer look at which variable's value you're printing. (Voting to close as typo.)

Comment: Yea I got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are setting maxtime = 10; then using the same to set time. But the value is not changed anywhere. So, the value remains 10.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your `time` to `maxTime` in your constructor and then you never touch it after.  It's literally the only time you modify the value of `time`.  In your `printResult()` you have your do/while loop, but that runs on `t < time`.

The bottom line is that you initialize `time` to 10, and then never modify the value.  you don't have a single `time -= 1` or `time +=1` in all of your code.

Try doing something like this:

```
void printResult()
{
    cout <<"t    S    I       R \n"<<endl;
while (time > 0)
{
    Runge_Kutta();
    time -=dt;
    cout<<time<<"   "<<susceptible<<"   "<<infected<<"   "<<recover<<"   "<<endl;
}
```